# ¿Por qué se pierde la reputación de SO en inglés en la version española?

Tags: soporte, stackexchange, reputación

Llevo años accediendo y colaborando en Stack Overflow en inglés. Al acceder a la version española, veo que aquí vuelvo a empezar de 0 con la reputación, ¿no se comparte entre todas las paginas de Stack Exchange?

Comment: Cada página tiene su reputación y son independientes entre sí. Yo tengo la StackOverflow en inglés y también me la creó de 0.

Comment: Aunque SOen  y SOes te puedan parecer el mismo sitio pero en distinto idioma, no es así. Cada uno es un sitio distinto con sus particularidades y reglas. Lo que es valido preguntar en uno puede no serlo en otro aunque compartan el ambito de programación. Un saludo y animo en este sitio para subir de reputacion y colaborar!

Comment: El problema es que en SO solo tienes 65 de reputación. Si tuvieras mas, empezarías con 100 en cualquier sitio de la red SE

Comment: Ok gracias a todos por la respuesta

Comment: ... y agrego a todo lo dicho, no es la "versión española" sino "en español"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sí, a efectos de reputación, cada comunidad tiene sus propios puntos y medallas que maneja de manera independiente. Estos puntos se pueden consultar en tu ficha de perfil: https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/87154/mimmetico

Lo único que es común entre comunidades son las preguntas tipo "meta", donde discute sobre temas relacionados con la propio plataforma. Puedes ver información aquí: [What is meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: Ok muchas gracias por la respuesta

Comment: En español: [¿Qué es "meta" y cómo funciona?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)